# Sinch Service In react-native

Tags: react-native, sinch

Has anyone tried linking sinch android SDK to react-native. Is it possible? I have been trying it for the past few days, haven't figured it out.

Comment: [Here](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/node-express-sinch/) is an example of conference call via node, it might be useful to get atleast an idea of how to use with `npm` and than `react-native`

Comment: The tutorial works only for app to mobile calling. It doesn't include app to app calling

Comment: Yes but it is showing you a way to use it, you can use rest api also as given in their [document](https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#apptoappcallingoverview) for app to app caliing

Comment: I tried using Rest api. It didn't work. I am left with only android SDK. Is there a way to link android SDK to react native

Comment: you can only use native SDK, not js SDK in reactnative. we don't have a reactnative plugin so you would have to build it on top of the native SDK.

Comment: I am trying with native SDK. But it isn't going well. Has anyone ever linked native SDK to react native